# How can I not show the selected on dropdown of mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use a mat-select as a popup menu which works fine, the problem i am facing isthat the mat-select by default shows what the user selected before by showing a diffrent background. If you use it as a value box this migght be ok, but when you use it as a menu it is not that great.
So my question is what values / style do i have to modify to make the previously selected item look the same as all the others.

I enclosed a sample on Stackblitz [Sample](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qlyjdgkgjbg?file=src/app/select-form-example.ts)

And here is the effect that i am talking about where Taco was previously selected

[image]

Comment: A bit harsh but don't use Angular Material if you need precise control on the style..

Comment: You can use `::ng-deep` to change the default style provided by angular material.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this styling is applied on the selected `mat-option` by the classes `mat-selected` and `mat-active`.

I tried removing these classes of selected `mat-option` using TypeScript.

Here is the solution I came up with:

I created a view child on the `mat-select` and created a `(click)` function on the `mat-select`. Then, whenever a user clicks on the `mat-select` I iterate over all its child `mat-option` and remove the classes `mat-selected` and `mat-active` from each.

Here are the changes I did:

**HTML File:**

```html
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food" #matOption (click)="removeSelectedClass($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**TypeScript File:**

```js
export class SelectFormExample {
    @ViewChildren('matOption') matOptions: QueryList<any>;
    
    removeSelectedClass(event: any) {
        this.matOptions.first.options._results.forEach((elem: any) => {
            elem._element.nativeElement.classList.remove('mat-selected', 'mat-active');
    });
}
```

You can find the sample solution developed by forking your sample code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mu1akd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-form-example.ts)

I hope this helps. Please let me know about any better approach to remove classes from the selected viewchild.

Answer (score 0):

You could override your styles by that:

```
.mat-select-panel .mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-multiple) 
{
  background: unset;
}
.mat-primary .mat-option.mat-selected:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
  color: unset;
}
.mat-option:hover:not(.mat-option-disabled), .mat-option:focus:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
  background: *your hovered option style* !important;
}
```